# meta（）関数を使用して、corpus でメタデータを確認できません。(映画レビューの感情分析)

Tags: r

洋書のプログラムなんですが、

```
meta(nb_all[[1]])
Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "character"
```

というエラーが出てしまいます。個人的に原因は二つのコーパスオブジェクトを結合できていないからと考えています。どうすれば`meta(nb_all[[1]])`が動くようになりますか？
以下プログラムです。

```
#映画レビューの感情分析
path_to_neg_folder <- "aclImdb/train/neg"
path_to_pos_folder <- "aclImdb/train/pos"
library("tm")
nb_pos <- Corpus(DirSource(path_to_pos_folder),
                   readerControl = list(language = "en"))
nb_neg <- Corpus(DirSource(path_to_neg_folder),
                   readerControl = list(language = "en"))
nb_all <- c(nb_pos, nb_neg, recursive = T)
#エラー
meta(nb_all[[1]])
Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "character"
```

データは二つのファイルに分かれています。データは映画の感想が書かれています。
`meta(nb_all[[1]])`も以下のようになってほしいです。

```
meta(nb_pos[[1]])
  author       : character(0)
  datetimestamp: 2020-05-16 08:55:32
  description  : character(0)
  heading      : character(0)
  id           : 0_9.txt
  language     : en
  origin       : character(0)
```

`str(nb_all)`を実行すると

```
> str(nb_all)
 Named chr [1:25002] "Bromwell High is a cartoon comedy. It ran at the same time as some other programs about school life, such as \""| __truncated__ ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:25002] "content.0_9.txt" "content.1_7.txt" "content.10_9.txt" "content.100_7.txt" ...
```

`str(nb_pos)`を実行すると（長いので最後だけ）

```
 $ 10085_10.txt:List of 2
  ..$ content: chr "I just saw this movie today with my children (son, 10 and daughter, 4.5) at the 3rd Annual Roger Ebert Overlook"| __truncated__
  ..$ meta   :List of 7
  .. ..$ author       : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ datetimestamp: POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2020-05-16 09:03:08"
  .. ..$ description  : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ heading      : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ id           : chr "10085_10.txt"
  .. ..$ language     : chr "en"
  .. ..$ origin       : chr(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "TextDocumentMeta"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "PlainTextDocument" "TextDocument"
  [list output truncated]
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "SimpleCorpus" "Corpus"
```

というふうになります。
`nb_pos`と`nb_all`で出てくる結果が違うので
うまく二つのコーパスをマージできていないと考えています。
どうすれば`meta(nb_all[[1]])`が動くようになりますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nb_pos` は `SimpleCorpus` クラスのインスタンスなのですが、

```
> class(nb_pos)
[1] "SimpleCorpus" "Corpus"
```

S3 generic function である `c` で結合(combine)するとリストになります。

```
> class(c(nb_pos, nb_neg))
[1] "list"

> names(c(nb_pos, nb_neg))
[1] "content" "meta"    "dmeta"   "content" "meta"    "dmeta"
```

nb_pos と nb_neg は同じキー("content", "meta", "dmeta")を持っているのですが、`c` での単純結合ではキー毎に結合してくれません。これは SimpleCorpus クラスで `tm_combine`(S3 generic function)が実装されていないからなので、以下の様にします。

```
> nb_all <- mapply(c, c(nb_pos), c(nb_neg))
> class(nb_all) <- class(nb_pos)
```

`nb_pos` と `nb_reg` をリストに変換してキー毎に要素を結合します。そして、`nb_all` のクラスを `SimpleCorpus` に設定します。